# tyles.css was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: magento, magento2

I have changed my hosting, now I am getting css/js blocked error `was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`. Please help me.

Please check js code which is giving me error.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/smart-keyboard-handler',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/ie-class-fixer',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, keyboardHandler) {
    'use strict';
    if ($('body').hasClass('checkout-cart-index')) {
        if ($('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates').length > 0 && $('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates :checked').length === 0) {
            $('#block-shipping').on('collapsiblecreate', function () {
                $('#block-shipping').collapsible('forceActivate');
            });
        }
    }

    $('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
        container: '#maincontent'
    });

    $('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');

    keyboardHandler.apply();
});
```

Comment: Are you referencing your files correctly?

Comment: yes i did correctly and i am facing issue after website move on new server

Comment: Then you are probably not referencing your files correctly. Post your reference code.

Comment: I had a similar problem and this solved it for me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152625/magento2-css-was-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch-x-content-type-options-nosn

Comment: I tried, but still the same issue

Comment: I have tried and post my ans here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/296528/82482

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I tried all the steps like

```
rm -rf var/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and still not worked. (These steps are required but it's incomplete)

You must have to change `.htaccess` file with a new one in `pub/static` **whether exists or not**.

After changing it, I ran `cache:clean` command again, and then it **works well** for me.

Most people might skip this step because .htaccess is already available in pub/static.

You can get `.htaccess` new one in magento official github:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/pub/static/.htaccess

(It's for Magento 2.3, and you can choose your appropriate version in branch)

P.S: If u got **memory exhausted** error while running the commands, try with

```
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento ...
```